# Ubuntu boots, Windows doesn't on New PC with old SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub2, dualboot, bootrepair

I installed a new motherboard, cpu and ram but unfortunately my Windows won't boot.

I have dual boot - Elementary OS and Windows 10. Elementary works just fine, but when I select Windows in the boot loader (grub 2) my screen either freezes or goes black. I tried reinstalling grub and elementary several times, but it didn't fix it. A friend recommended me boot-repair and I tried it, but it didn't work. Here's the output:

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20210107_2036]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================



The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
sda6 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because: legacy-win no-win-efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix


Quantity of real Windows: 1

=================== Several (2) /boot folders exist in sda1/ and may disturb os-prober, boot renamed into oldbooot.
mv: cannot move '/mnt/boot-sav/sda1/boot' to '/mnt/boot-sav/sda1/oldbooot': Read-only file system

GRUB detected inside Windows partition. sda1/boot/grub renamed into boot/grub_old
mv: cannot move '/mnt/boot-sav/sda1/boot/grub' to '/mnt/boot-sav/sda1/boot/grub_old': Read-only file system

========================= Reinstall the grub2 of sda6 ==========================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.20+elementary25~ubuntu5.1.7.1

==> Reinstall the GRUB of sda6 into the MBR of sda

grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[61649]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 18255: /bin/sh
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera CurrentSession on sda6
OS#2:   Windows 10 (boot) on sda1
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=30cc4cf0-7fec-4a6d-ab4d-41dd4d88c422 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1


===================================== UEFI =====================================

This installed-session is not in EFI-mode.

2895d47544fd587b26c7e29be1295c27   sda5/BOOT/fbx64.efi
8397fda3d5c75c13763a6e89721948f7   sda5/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda5/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda5/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda5/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xcf505f64
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2  *       206848 434887182 434680335 207.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       434888704 435967999   1079296   527M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
sda4       435970046 488396799  52426754    25G  5 Extended
sda5       487397376 488396799    999424   488M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda6       435970048 487397375  51427328  24.5G 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:250GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Samsung SSD 850:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:ntfs::;
2:106MB:223GB:223GB:ntfs::boot;
3:223GB:223GB:553MB:ntfs::diag;
4:223GB:250GB:26.8GB:::;
6:223GB:250GB:26.3GB:ext4::;
5:250GB:250GB:512MB:fat32::esp;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                           
├─sda1 ntfs   B4FC7F32FC7EEE4C                     cf505f64-01                                
├─sda2 ntfs   B6E05206E051CCED                     cf505f64-02                          SSD   
├─sda3 ntfs   30FCE42EFCE3EBD2                     cf505f64-03                                
├─sda5 vfat   EC09-B3B3                            cf505f64-05                                
└─sda6 ext4   30cc4cf0-7fec-4a6d-ab4d-41dd4d88c422 cf505f64-06                                

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1    61.7M  38% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2   106.3G  49% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda3    88.9M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda5     481M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sda6    17.2G  23% /

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda2   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda3   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda6   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1

===================== sda5/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 30cc4cf0-7fec-4a6d-ab4d-41dd4d88c422 root hd0,msdos6 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

elementary   30cc4cf0-7fec-4a6d-ab4d-41dd4d88c422
elementary, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic   30cc4cf0-7fec-4a6d-ab4d-41dd4d88c422
Windows 10 (on sda1)   B4FC7F32FC7EEE4C
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda6/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=30cc4cf0-7fec-4a6d-ab4d-41dd4d88c422 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda5 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 210.120189667 = 225.614835712  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 212.260025024 = 227.912466432  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 211.082027435 = 226.647601152  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic                  2
 211.082027435 = 226.647601152  vmlinuz                                        2
 212.536018372 = 228.208812032  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic               2
 212.536018372 = 228.208812032  initrd.img                                     2
 212.536018372 = 228.208812032  initrd.img.old                                 2

===================== sda6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12798 Nov 24 16:13 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Nov 24 16:13 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Nov 24 16:13 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Nov 24 16:13 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Nov 24 16:13 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Nov 24 16:13 41_custom


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4



=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

hexdump: /dev/sda4: No such device or address
hexdump: /dev/sda4: No such device or address
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[61649]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 6443: /bin/bash
paste2.org ko (http://paste2.org/)
```

In Gparted there's a warning symbol next to /dev/sda2 (Windows) and "rightclick -> Check" gave me the error below. Also I put my "ntfsfix" and "fdisk -l" outputs at the bottom. I read, that running Windows directly from the boot menu can help, but unfortunately my boot menu doesn't give me that choice. Also I don't think reinstalling Windows is an option. All my important files are backed up, but Windows was preinstalled on the PC and I dont have the product key. So reinstalling Windows would mean losing my license.

This is my first post, as usually I've been able to fix all my problems myself. So if I've done something wrong (I probably have), I'm sorry.

It would be very nice If someone could help me

GParted Output:

```
Libparted 3.2

Check and repair file system (ntfs) on /dev/sda2  00:00:04    ( ERROR )
        
calibrate /dev/sda2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sda2 (partition)
start: 206848
end: 434887182
size: 434680335 (207.27 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda2 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:04    ( ERROR )
        
ntfsresize -i -f -v '/dev/sda2'  00:00:04    ( ERROR )
        
ntfsresize v2017.3.23 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda2
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 222556328448 bytes (222557 MB)
Current device size: 222556331520 bytes (222557 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Cluster accounting failed at 7183535 (0x6d9caf): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Filesystem check failed! Totally 1 cluster accounting mismatches.
ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.
```

ntfsfix output:

```
ben@BensPC2:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

fdisk output:

```
ben@BensPC2:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcf505f64

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       206848 434887182 434680335 207,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       434888704 435967999   1079296   527M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       435970046 488396799  52426754    25G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       487397376 488396799    999424   488M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda6       435970048 487397375  51427328  24,5G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean reinstall Windows no matter what. No amount of tests, commands and boot-repairs is going to cut it, it's just plainly impossible to boot into Windows 10 after hardware change, after you changed the hardware it is, for all intents and purposes, a different computer. As far as I know, the only Windows thing currently available that can boot on different machines is Windows Preinstallation Environment, which is used to install Windows OS to computers, it is very specialised and trimmed down, limited in functionality and not suitable for a general purpose operating system.

There was WindowsToGo which was like Linux LiveCDs, it can boot on different computers and served as a general purpose OS, unfortunately it is discontinued.

You can't boot Windows on different computers because of the drivers, drivers are pieces of softwares that acts as the medium between the operating system and hardware, it speaks hardware, it receives commands from the OS and issues them to the hardware.

You need a driver for each hardware, for example, you need drivers for CPU, RAM, GPU, HDD, Motherboard, Mouse and Keyboard... Everything in your computer, you need a driver for it, otherwise it simply won't work.

Some drivers are general purpose, you only need one driver for all devices of the same type, for example, Windows has only one driver for all disk storage devices, because they conform to SATA standard, they speak the same language, this type of drivers is generic;

However you need different drivers for different motherboard, CPU, GPU and sound card, because they are built under different standards, they don't speak the same language; A hardware can't understand a driver that speaks another hardware.

You can boot WinPE on different computers because it doesn't have specialised drivers, so any computer can understand it, but as its drivers are general purpose, they are not tailored to the hardware therefore can't effeciently utilise the hardware.

The drivers are stored in C:\Windows\System32\drivers folder. When Windows is installing, it automatically detects the hardware and installs suitable drivers for the hardware so they can be used. This process is called initializiation.
The drivers are hardware specific and can't be used for different hardwares.